# Salesforce Web to lead only working in debug mode

Tags: html, forms, salesforce

I'm using a salesforce web to lead form. If I turn debug mode on, it sends the email (albeit a few minutes after hitting send). If I turn debugging off, nothing is sent.

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" id="contactForm">
    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="{{my company id}}">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://site.co/thanks">
    <input  id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" class="full-width" placeholder="NAME"/>
    <input  id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="EMAIL" class="full-width"/>

    <!--
    <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>
    <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="rob@site.co">
    -->

    <textarea name="description" class="full-width" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn pull-right" value="Send Message" tabindex="5">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you know the email is not being sent or do you just not see the Lead from your test?  How are you verifying it works?

Comment: When debug mode is on, we get a confirmation email and the lead shows up. When it's off, we go no email and no lead shows up.

Comment: I read about other folks having similar issue and it turned out they were just not looking in the right place for non-debug leads.

Comment: Is there another place to look other than the main leads list?